# How to print each object of an array of objects in a new line in txt file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, formatting

My result set is an array of objects that returns from a function.

```
[{brand:"Toyota", model: "Prius"}, {brand:"Subaru", model:"WRX"}, {brand:"Honda", model: "Accord"}]
```

I am writing it into a file using

```
fs.writeFile('test.txt', array, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

The "text.txt" looks like this:

```
[{brand:"Toyota", model: "Prius"},{brand:"Subaru", model:"WRX"},{brand:"Honda", model: "Accord"}]
```

How could i print them in format like this:

```
{brand:"Toyota", model: "Prius"}
{brand:"Subaru", model:"WRX"}
{brand:"Honda", model: "Accord"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing a function

```
let arr = [{brand:"Toyota", model: "Prius"}, {brand:"Subaru", model:"WRX"}, {brand:"Honda", model: "Accord"}];

function mapLine(_arr, i){
  let a = [];
  _arr.forEach((item)=>{
    newLine = i === 0 ? "" : "\r\n";
    a.push(newLine + JSON.stringify(item));
  })
  return a;
}

fs.writeFile('test.txt', mapLine(arr), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```